# How do I show progress of a long-running server operation (Web API Commanding) in the Lightswitch HTML client?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, asp.net-web-api, lightswitch-2013

I have a VS 2013 Lightswitch HTML Client application to which I've added a button that makes a Web API REST post.  This basically 'refreshes' the data in the table from the original upstream source.  This is all working correctly, but the operation takes a few minutes, and I want to report status to the user as it runs.

Right now, I've tried attaching a simple Refresh when the post returns as follows:

```
 $.post("/api/data/", "Refresh", function (response) {
        screen.getData().then(function (newData) { screen.reQuery(); });
    });
```

This doesn't actually seem to do a refresh (screen.reQuery is apparently the wrong call), but the better option would be to instead have the server show progress of this long-running application.

One thought I had would be to have the server call return data in the form of "percent done" in the response as it processes it, but I don't know if this would be delivered to the client piecemeal, nor the best way to display this to the user in Lightswitch.

I'm open to other third-party libraries that might help with this, but I'd like to stick with WebAPI for commanding instead of adding something like SignalR for now, if possible.  Thanks!

Comment: I will not go into full trouble of making an answer, but I will give a few guidelines: 1. Run your long operation in a separate thread, so you wont block the request that called it. 2. Store your progress information by unique id in session or some thread safe object. 3. Make web service or something similar that will return progres information form stored progress state. 4. In you page make a script that will in regular intervals query web service (or other method) for progress. 5. Display progress on your page. Summary: not simple.

Answer (score -2):

In general this seems like not the best idea to run operations that takes minutes on the server.

A reasonable alternative is to create a single call, that will in turn create multiple Web Jobs (see Azure Web Jobs for more info). The Web Jobs will be broken to smaller individual tasks, and your html will query the web jobs rather than your Web API.

Comment: This isn't an Azure application.

Comment: Sure, Azure just makes it easy to manage long running jobs. I'll still post it to another service, managing a queue of long running operations and providing status.

Comment: I down voted because the OP asked for guidance on how to implement, not an opinion on best practice. His question is a good question.

Comment: @bflemi3 this is not an opinion on best practice. Running minute long operations in IIS is wrong and unreliable. The server can shutdown on you, switching to background tasks is not recommended either. The way to fix it is to write something else that processes long operations in a queue. Yes someone (including me) can show a hacky way to fix it that will work some of the time.